# text typing animation in AS2 randomly switches two characters when generating from string

Tags: flash, settimeout, actionscript-2, charat

I'm making an interactive comic showing dialogue between two characters. I used this tutorial: http://frameentered.com/content/typing-effect-flash-as2 to create a typing text animation. I'm using AS2 in Flash Pro CS6.

It works great except sometimes two characters in the string will be swapped. for example, one part of dialogue will output "tos ay" rather than "to say" (as it is in the code) or "Wel,l" instead of "Well,"

Regenerating the text (by clicking to the next frame then back) usually fixes it. But this happens fairly often in many different frames, no idea why.

Also, I have the next/prev buttons on a timer to enable only after the text finishes, to prevent garbling it with the next/previous frame's (they all use the same dynamic text field). That's the part I added to what was in the tutorial, so maybe I screwed something up.

the swf so far is here: http://sta.sh/0owl7iiqx5o

my code is:

```
_root.nextbtn.enabled = false;
_root.prevbtn.enabled = false;

//speed of typing (ms)
var speed:Number = 30;

//what shall be typed
var msg1:String = "Easy for you to say.";

//where it shall be typed
typeText(msg1,tf1);


//makes the typing happen
function typeText(msg:String, tf:TextField)
{
    for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++)
    {
        setTimeout(addChar,speed * i,msg.charAt(i),tf);
    }
}

//button timer: must load AFTER setTimeout(addChar)^
var btnTimer:Number = setTimeout(enBTN, speed * i);

//adds letters
function addChar(char:String, tf:TextField)
{
    tf.text += char;
}
//enables buttons
function enBTN()
{
    _root.nextbtn.enabled = true;
    _root.prevbtn.enabled = true;
}
```

many thanks!

Comment: could you show us the setTimeout function you've got?

Comment: @drake Not sure what you mean? that's everything

Comment: oops sorry ha ha I had never used the setTimeout function before, I thought you had created the function. I'll do my best to figure out the answer to your problem though